# Setting timeout with testNG and Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I've got a problem with testing in Java. I'm using TestNG & Selenium. I wanted to run a method with annotaion @Test on long period of time, but it stopped in about 5000 seconds. I've tried to set attribute Timeout, but it didn't work for me. How can I control execution time of test method?

Sometimes I've noticed that my test method before stop after around 5000 seconds threw exception "org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **WebDriver Wait** and **Wait Until Expected Conditions** before Performing Any Action on Any Element, So that testcases Never Fails due to Timing Issues

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);// Maximum TimeOut
    PageUtil.refreshObject(driver, By.linkText("Link_yu_want_to_click"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Link_yu_want_to_click")));
```